# How do I add the value -1 in front of odd numbered elements in a C++ vector, I have problems using the insert function

Tags: c++

```
int main ()
{
    vector < int  > v;
    v = initialize (v);
    cout << "Initial Vector: " << endl;
    print (v);
    cout << "Adding -1 in front of Odds: " << endl;
    v = insert_odds(v);
    cout << "Final Vector: " << endl;
    print(v);
}

double random (unsigned int &seed)
{
    const int MODULUS = 15749;
    const int MULTIPLIER = 69069;
    const int INCREMENT = 1;
    seed = ((MULTIPLIER * seed) + INCREMENT) % MODULUS;
    return double (seed) / double (MODULUS);
}

vector <int > initialize (vector < int > v)
{
    unsigned int seed=2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        v.push_back(int (10 + (10 * random (seed))));
    return v;
}

void print (vector < int > v)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
bool isOdd(int n)
{
    return n%2 != 0 && n > 0;
}

vector<int> insert_odds(vector <int> v)
{
    std::vector<int>::iterator it = find_if(v.begin(),v.end(),isOdd);
    while(it  != v.end())
    {
         it = find_if(v.begin(),v.end(),isOdd);
         v.insert(it,-1);
    }
    return v;
}
```

This is the code I have.
The vector at the beginning is 
17 10 14 16 15 19 19 10 14 18
and I want the output to be
-1 17 10 14 16 -1 15 -1 19 -1 19 10 14 18

As of right now the program runs but doesn't have an output.

Comment: *Title explains it* -- No it doesn't.  Show your code.

Comment: Please elaborate on your problem. Show a [mcve] with what you've tried and use that to explain your thinking of why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to **insert** new elements into a vector while iterating through it, you have two choices:

1. make use of the `iterator` that `insert()` returns:

   ```
   vector<int>::iterator iter = myVector.begin();
   while (iter != myVector.end())
   {
       if ((*iter % 2) != 0)
           iter = myVector.insert(iter, -1) + 2;
       else
           ++iter;
   }
   ```
2. use indexes instead of iterators:

   ```
   vector<int>::size_type idx = 0;
   while (idx < myVector.size())
   {
       if ((myVector[idx] % 2) != 0)
       {
           myVector.insert(myVector.begin()+idx, -1);
           idx += 2;
       }
       else
           ++idx;
   }
   ```

Comment: SERIOUS props for even understanding what the question was without clarification.

Comment: error: no matching member function for call to 'insert'
            myVector.insert(idx, -1);

Comment: You can still use iterators - `insert` returns one.

Comment: Can you elaborate how?

Comment: I'm sure it won't be a good homework answer, but I would just copy each element to a new vector, and if the element is odd, add a `-1` to the new vector before copying.

Comment: I did that but i am required to use insert

Comment: @RikTor my bad, I forgot that `insert()` takes an `iterator` as input. I fixed my answer.

Comment: @chris good point. Not all containers do that in all C++ versions, but `vector` does. I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the return value from `vector::insert()` :

```
vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
{
    if (*it & 1)
    {
        it = v.insert(it, -1);
        it++;
    }
}
```